# XMLHttpRequest javascript POST-request issue "cannot load url"

Tags: javascript, json, post, xmlhttprequest

```
var http = {};

http.request = (function () {
    function send(jsonObject, url) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", url);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        req.send(jsonString);
    }
    return {
        send: send
    };
})();
```

I am trying to use this javascript function to send data. However it gives me an error:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load *url*. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That sounds like Same Origin Policy. Is the url for another domain?

Comment: Give the URL you are requesting and where are you requesting from.

Comment: why have you embedded ajax call inside self invoking anonymous function.
Its basic function is to excute script without making them global

Comment: I get the issue in url: http://httpbin.org/post and others as well. I dont think  the issue has to do with the url.

Comment: I noticed that the issue is caused by the content-type being "application/json". I have the same issue while using JQuerys ajax to send data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the content-type to be json, this is considered a preflighted request.  What this means is that essentially two requests are being made: the first one asks the server permission to make a request, and the second one is the actual request.  For such cases, you need to at least check for origin of the request on your server side:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your origin url')
```

You might also have to check the request method:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST')
```